# Changing the value of a boolean variable with class methods?

Tags: java

So I am messing around with java and came across a problem with some code I am trying to write.

I have made a class called `LogicGate` in this class there are methods to set the state of the instance of `LogicGate` to either true or false.

`LogicGate` only has one attribute and its a boolean value true or false.

All the methods seem to work but the one (called not()) where I am changing the boolean value to false if true and true if false.

The code changes the value the first time from true to false but the second time it seems to ignore the if statement.

```
//Main

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LogicGate logicGate = new LogicGate(true);

        System.out.println(logicGate.state());
        System.out.println("");

        logicGate.not(logicGate);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println(logicGate.state());
        System.out.println("");

        logicGate.not(logicGate);
    }

}

//Class Logicgate


public class LogicGate {
    //The attribute for the for the object
    private boolean state;

    //Creating the constructor for the object logic gate 
    public LogicGate(boolean logicGateState) {
        state = logicGateState;
    }

    //This method changes the state of the Logic Gate
    public  void not(LogicGate obj) {

        //Saving the current state of the logic gate
        boolean currentState = obj.state();

        System.out.println("....." + currentState);

        //Checks the state of the object instance and changes it accordingly
        if(currentState = true) {
            obj.negate(obj);
            System.out.println("The state has changed to: " + obj.state() + " Should be false");
        }
        else if(currentState = false) {     
            obj.set(obj);
            System.out.println("The state has changed to: " + obj.state() + " Should be true");

        }


    }

    //Sets the state of the object boolean variable to true 
    public  void set(LogicGate obj) {
        obj.setState(true);

    }



    //Sets the state of the object boolean variable to false 
    public  void negate(LogicGate obj) { 
        obj.setState(false);

    }

    //This method will return the state of the object
    //it can be either true or false 
    public boolean state() {
        return state;
    }

    //Sets the boolean attribute 
    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }


}
```

The boolean value should just change every time the not method is called.

The final line of the code should say `The state has changed to: true Should be true`.

The result I am getting is:

```
true

.....true
The state has changed to: false Should be false

false

.....false
The state has changed to: false Should be false
```

Comment: Typo.  You're using `=` for comparison, it should be `==`.

Comment: `if(currentState == true)` instead of `if(currentState = true)`, and likewise for the false clause.

Comment: @ David, @ Avi, Thanks I rely appreciate the help, im new to java what a silly mistake.

Comment: Actually, preferred style is to use `if (currentState)` or `if (!currentState)`.  It is superfluous to use a `conditional expression` to evaluate a `boolean` since the conditional evaluates to a `boolean`.

Comment: In addition to being superfluous, it is error-prone for the exact thing you encountered: using `=` instead of `==`. If instead you do `if (currentState) { ... }` there is no chance of making an assignment that you didn't intend to make. If you do still want to be verbose, a safer way is to flip the boolean statement: `if (true == currentState) { ... }` – that way, if you have a single `=`, you'll get a compiler error that you can't assign a value to `true`.

Comment: `currentState = !currentState;`. If it's true it will end up false. If it's false it will end up true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of issues, namely:

1. The operator **=** is an assignment operator. You are doing comparisons, which means you need to use the **==** operator.
2. For `boolean` values you don't actually need to use a comparison operator in an if, because it's either `true` or `false` (not true).
3. If your first `if` is checking for a `true` then your else logically is checking for `false`

So you code should rather look something like this:

```
if(currentState) {
  obj.negate(obj);
  System.out.println("The state has changed to: " + obj.state() + " Should be false");
} else {
  obj.set(obj);
  System.out.println("The state has changed to: " + obj.state() + " Should be true");
}
```

I also don't understand however why you passing in the `LogicGate` object into a method of `LogicGate`, to set the state of a variable contained within `LogicGate` (or for any of `LogicGates` methods for that matter). Why don't you just use the method you already have `setState(boolean state)`, then your implementation would just be:

```
if(currentState) {
  obj.setState(Boolean.FALSE);
  System.out.println("The state has changed to: " + obj.state() + " Should be false");
} else {
  obj.setState(Boolean.TRUE);
  System.out.println("The state has changed to: " + obj.state() + " Should be true");
}
```

Ultimately though, your `not()` method should just be as simple as :

```
public void not() {
  this.state = !state;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change all single = to "==" or destructor code

```
 if(currentState) {

            obj.negate(obj);
            System.out.println("The state has changed to: " + obj.state() + " Should be false");
        }
        else{     
            obj.set(obj);
            System.out.println("The state has changed to: " + obj.state() + " Should be true");
```

tell me if it work